# Double click on a button with Protractor

Tags: protractor

Snippet Code:

```
<div class="add create_Amenities" hs-gesture="{handler:showPopup, param:menu_group}" ng-if="showPlus(menu_group,$index)">
```

Desired action: Double click on a button which would proceed to the next page.

I enter the below command, my browser comes up but I have to manually click on the “Add” button one more time to proceed to the next page. The command does one click

Question:  How can I make this command a double clicked on the (Add) button. I tried it different ways but I was not successful. Any ideas?

```
browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('.add.create_Amenities'))).perform();

element.all(by.css('.add.create_Amenities')).then(function (elm) {

    elm[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Can you just call `click()` twice?  `elm[0].click(); elm[0].click();`

Comment: There are ways of doing this in protractor such as `browser.actions().doubleClick(element).perform();`     https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2989    unfortunately there is a bug associated with it and until the issue is corrected I would just click the element twice maybe write a doubleClick helper function.

Comment: I tried to click the element twice as suggested but still the button is not being clicked for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used multiples helps from online community and I made the Double click working for me. The key for me to work was to have 1 sec of delay between each click. If I remove the delay, the double click does not occur.

```
var AddButton = element(by.css(".add.create_Amenities" ));
browser.actions().mouseDown(AddButton).mouseUp().perform();
browser.sleep(1000);    
browser.actions().mouseMove(AddButton).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let addButton = $('.add.create_Amenities');
addButton.click();
addButton.click();
```

Or if you prefer actions:

```
let addButton = $('.add.create_Amenities');

browser.actions()
    .click(addButton)
    .click(addButton)
.perform();

// Didn't tried this:
browser.actions().doubleClick(addButton).perform();
```

Comment: I tried your suggested commands but it just would not click on the "Add" button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(browser.element(by.css('.add.create_Amenities'))).perform();
```

Comment: Nick, I tried your suggested command it but it would not click on the button

Comment: what was the error? [Try to Debug] (https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.enterRepl)

Comment: No Error at all. Just does not click on the element.